# 1. Как с помощью bat файла узнать где лежит этот файл? 2. Как задать системную переменную в cmd, которая не исчезнет после перезагрузки?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

1. Как с помощью bat файла узнать где лежит этот файл?

   Бат файл выполняет python скрипт, но при запуске его, он начинает путь с c:\User\ а, надо чтобы запускался с места где лежит байт файл, причем все это должно быть не жестко привязано.
2. Как задать системную переменную в cmd, которая не исчезнет после перезагрузки?

   При вводе Set path = %path%variable в системную перемену добавляется строка variable, но после перезагрузки системы она исчезает. Как сделать чтобы не исчезала?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Нулевым параметром в любой bat-файл передается путь к нему. Применение модификатора позволяет получить папку:

   ```
   echo %~dp0
   ```

---

2. Добавить запись в реестр:

   ```
   % reg add HKCU\Environment /v VariableName /t REG_SZ /d "Variable value"
   ```

Переменная станет видимой после следующего входа в систему.

Answer (score 1):

По второму вопросу запись в реестр вручную неудобен, т.к. изменение не действует на текущий сеанс.
Ответ в команде:

setx /?

С учетом замечаний дополню ответ.
Необходимо воспользоваться в скрипте двумя командами. Первая записывает параметр в реестр для будущих сеансов. Вторая команда задает значение параметра для текущего сеанса.

```
@setx var0 Value
@set var0=Value
```

Comment: Ответ также есть в гугле. Но у нас тут принято не посылать людей за ответом, а давать ответ самому. Стековерфлоу, в отличие от гугла, не источник ссылок, а источник _информации_.

Comment: это да, но переменные, установленные через setx, все равно недоступны без перезапуска cmd. так что разница небольшая чем пользоваться